# Find PHP functions in source code?

Tags: php, c++, c

Generally, is it a good idea to copy the source code of the PHP interpreter and use it on your C/C++ program, or something is wrong with this in terms of performance and reliability?

Comment: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/url.c found via: http://lxr.php.net/search?q=rawurlencode&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=PHP_5_4

Comment: Don't copy the [function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/94e15ff3877f842e5eb5c89e3aeab214fb4a3a33/ext/standard/url.c#L633), try to use it,

Comment: Is it really that hard to search in the Github you linked us to?  https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/94e15ff3877f842e5eb5c89e3aeab214fb4a3a33/ext/standard/url.c

Comment: sorry... basicly, with this logic, i can write c/c++ functions and add them to php without exec?

Comment: I tried searching but I can't find the array os_toascii. Can someone please tell me how to find it's source code, please?

Comment: There's `git grep`. Just saying.

Comment: Yes but the array is never initialized and used only here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/94e15ff3877f842e5eb5c89e3aeab214fb4a3a33/ext/standard/url.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it is probably not useful in many cases because PHP handles data with its own Variant and you probably won't have those in your C/C++ program.

However, using the work they've done and implementing your own version is certainly a good idea but really only from elaborate PHP functions. For example, for array handling, you probably just want to use the C++ std::map (or std::vector) and be done with it.

Note also that PHP is written to run under many operating systems so you'll see overly complicated things in functions that make use of OS specific libraries. If you are programming for one specific target, it will be simpler for you to just implement your own instead of copy/paste + modify.